# can you link a css file through html?

Tags: html, css, webserver

I just need some clarification about linking a css file.  I am looking at a html widget that has been created by someone and they seem to have a html with a query string to get the required css..

```
<link href="https://cdnres.willyweather.com.au/widget/cssView.1-12-8.html?id=36723" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this works if you click on this link

http://cdnres.willyweather.com.au/widget/loadView.html?id=36723

But when i downloaded these files onto my own web server and tried it, it didn't work
http://www.mccdepot.com.au/Test1/loadView.html

but when I update the link styles to a css and updated the file name it worked.
http://www.mccdepot.com.au/Test2/loadView.html

For the query string html do I need to enable something on the server side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my code, i have updated css and js file links

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i copied that link css add it to your code its coming same as given link i have added the screen shot check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path of the css file"/>
```

This is how normally we include a css file in our html page. If still getting error, please check the file path properly.

Answer (score 0):

your linked css file is minified, check it once. When you minify some
    css files actually it replaces some variables. Try again to download
    again and link it. And js files also not included properly, when it
    check it in viewsource file was not found there